# Вывод числа в двоичном виде Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Например, у меня есть такие переменные:

```
nAdr db 104 dup(0)
Caption0 db "START", 0
```

Как мне вывести этот массив в `MessageBox`?
При таком раскладе ничего не выводит:

```
invoke MessageBox, 0, ADDR nAdr, ADDR Caption0, 0
```

Comment: Окошко хотя бы появляется при запуске? Имя окна правильно выводится?

Comment: да, данных нету

Comment: А что именно у вас находится в nAdr ? в том что вы показали там вообще двоичные нули и они не могут быть выведены, потому что вывод до нуля как раз работает. И что вы кстати имеете ввиду "вывод в двоичном виде" ? Это в виде 0 и 1 ?

Comment: Ну тогда все понятно, читайте коммент выше. У вас массив состоит из 104 нулей, а вывод происходит до завершающего нуля как признака конца строки. Необходимо в массив положить хорошие данные и конце обязательно 0.